# multiply numpy ndarray with 1d array along a given axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

It seems I am getting lost in something potentially silly.
 I have an n-dimensional numpy array, and I want to multiply it with a vector (1d array) along some dimension (which can change!).
As an example, say I want to multiply a 2d array by a 1d array along axis 0 of the first array, I can do something like this:

```
a=np.arange(20).reshape((5,4))
b=np.ones(5)
c=a*b[:,np.newaxis]
```

Easy, but I would like to extend this idea to n-dimensions (for a, while b is always 1d) and to any axis. In other words, I would like to know how to generate a slice with the np.newaxis at the right place. Say that a is 3d and I want to multiply along axis=1, I would like to generate the slice which would correctly give:

```
c=a*b[np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis]
```

I.e. given the number of dimensions of a (say 3), and the axis along which I want to multiply (say axis=1), how do I generate and pass the slice:

```
np.newaxis,:,np.newaxis
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have data on an ndarray, and I would like to multiply the data with a filter along some axis.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Solution Code -**

```
import numpy as np

# Given axis along which elementwise multiplication with broadcasting 
# is to be performed
given_axis = 1

# Create an array which would be used to reshape 1D array, b to have 
# singleton dimensions except for the given axis where we would put -1 
# signifying to use the entire length of elements along that axis  
dim_array = np.ones((1,a.ndim),int).ravel()
dim_array[given_axis] = -1

# Reshape b with dim_array and perform elementwise multiplication with 
# broadcasting along the singleton dimensions for the final output
b_reshaped = b.reshape(dim_array)
mult_out = a*b_reshaped
```

**Sample run for a demo of the steps -**

```
In [149]: import numpy as np

In [150]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,2,3))

In [151]: b = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,1)).ravel()

In [152]: whos
Variable   Type       Data/Info
-------------------------------
a          ndarray    4x2x3: 24 elems, type `int32`, 96 bytes
b          ndarray    2: 2 elems, type `int32`, 8 bytes

In [153]: given_axis = 1
```

Now, we would like to perform elementwise multiplications along `given axis = 1`. Let's create `dim_array`:

```
In [154]: dim_array = np.ones((1,a.ndim),int).ravel()
     ...: dim_array[given_axis] = -1
     ...: 

In [155]: dim_array
Out[155]: array([ 1, -1,  1])
```

Finally, reshape `b` & perform the elementwise multiplication:

```
In [156]: b_reshaped = b.reshape(dim_array)
     ...: mult_out = a*b_reshaped
     ...:
```

Check out the `whos` info again and pay special attention to `b_reshaped` & `mult_out`:

```
In [157]: whos
Variable     Type       Data/Info
---------------------------------
a            ndarray    4x2x3: 24 elems, type `int32`, 96 bytes
b            ndarray    2: 2 elems, type `int32`, 8 bytes
b_reshaped   ndarray    1x2x1: 2 elems, type `int32`, 8 bytes
dim_array    ndarray    3: 3 elems, type `int32`, 12 bytes
given_axis   int        1
mult_out     ndarray    4x2x3: 24 elems, type `int32`, 96 bytes
```

Comment: Ok, my fault I did not mention this: I cannot generate copies of b with appropriate size matching a, since a can be very very big.

Comment: Hey, no, sorry, it actually is a solution, I had misunderstood it. Great, thanks!

Comment: @AJC It's ok really! Removing my earlier comment.

Comment: I'm always surprised by just how powerful numpy is. Cool! Thanks again.

Comment: @AJC I found out the same in the past one month! :)

Comment: In one line: `shape = [ -1 if ax == given_axis else 1 for ax in range(a.ndim)]`, and then do your calculation `a*b.reshape(shape)`.

Answer (score 6):

Avoid copying data and waste resources!

Utilizing casting and views, instead of actually copying data N times into a new array with appropriate shape (as existing answers do) is way more memory efficient. Here is such a method (based on @ShuxuanXU's code):

```
def mult_along_axis(A, B, axis):

    # ensure we're working with Numpy arrays
    A = np.array(A)
    B = np.array(B)

    # shape check
    if axis >= A.ndim:
        raise AxisError(axis, A.ndim)
    if A.shape[axis] != B.size:
        raise ValueError(
            "Length of 'A' along the given axis must be the same as B.size"
            )

    # np.broadcast_to puts the new axis as the last axis, so 
    # we swap the given axis with the last one, to determine the
    # corresponding array shape. np.swapaxes only returns a view
    # of the supplied array, so no data is copied unnecessarily.
    shape = np.swapaxes(A, A.ndim-1, axis).shape

    # Broadcast to an array with the shape as above. Again, 
    # no data is copied, we only get a new look at the existing data.
    B_brc = np.broadcast_to(B, shape)

    # Swap back the axes. As before, this only changes our "point of view".
    B_brc = np.swapaxes(B_brc, A.ndim-1, axis)

    return A * B_brc
```

Answer (score 5):

You could build a slice object, and select the desired dimension in that:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(18).reshape((3,2,3))
b = np.array([1,3])

ss = [None] * a.ndim    
ss[1] = slice(None)    # set the dimension along which to broadcast

print ss  #  [None, slice(None, None, None), None]

c = a*b[tuple(ss)]  # convert to tuple to avoid FutureWarning from newer versions of Python
```

Comment: I like this solution as it avoids copying, follows the line of thinking of the questioner and is pretty easy to follow. I think `None] * a.ndim` is equivalent to `[None for i in range(a.ndim)]` but looks simpler

Comment: Python3: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

Comment: @klmn: I just tried this code in python 3.9.12 and numpy 1.21.5 and it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: Should be a tuple, not a list: `ss = tuple((None if i != axis else slice(None) for i in range(a.ndim)))`

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying @Neinstein's solution, I arrived at

```
def multiply_along_axis(A, B, axis):
    return np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(A, axis, -1) * B, -1, axis)
```

This example also avoids copying and wasting memory. The explicit broadcasting is avoided by swapping the desired axis in A to the last position, perform the multiplication, and than swapping the axis back to the original position. The additional advantage is that numpy takes care of the error handling and type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar demand when I was working on some numerical calculation.

Let's assume we have two arrays (A and B) and a user-specified 'axis'. 
A is a multi-dimensional array. 
B is a 1-d array.

The basic idea is to expand B so that A and B have the same shape. Here is the solution code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core._internal import AxisError

def multiply_along_axis(A, B, axis):
    A = np.array(A)
    B = np.array(B)
    # shape check
    if axis >= A.ndim:
        raise AxisError(axis, A.ndim)
    if A.shape[axis] != B.size:
        raise ValueError("'A' and 'B' must have the same length along the given axis")
    # Expand the 'B' according to 'axis':
    # 1. Swap the given axis with axis=0 (just need the swapped 'shape' tuple here)
    swapped_shape = A.swapaxes(0, axis).shape
    # 2. Repeat:
    # loop through the number of A's dimensions, at each step:
    # a) repeat 'B':
    #    The number of repetition = the length of 'A' along the 
    #    current looping step; 
    #    The axis along which the values are repeated. This is always axis=0,
    #    because 'B' initially has just 1 dimension
    # b) reshape 'B':
    #    'B' is then reshaped as the shape of 'A'. But this 'shape' only 
    #     contains the dimensions that have been counted by the loop
    for dim_step in range(A.ndim-1):
        B = B.repeat(swapped_shape[dim_step+1], axis=0)\
             .reshape(swapped_shape[:dim_step+2])
    # 3. Swap the axis back to ensure the returned 'B' has exactly the 
    # same shape of 'A'
    B = B.swapaxes(0, axis)
    return A * B
```

And here is an example

```
In [33]: A = np.random.rand(3,5)*10; A = A.astype(int); A
Out[33]: 
array([[7, 1, 4, 3, 1],
       [1, 8, 8, 2, 4],
       [7, 4, 8, 0, 2]])

In [34]: B = np.linspace(3,7,5); B
Out[34]: array([3., 4., 5., 6., 7.])

In [35]: multiply_along_axis(A, B, axis=1)
Out[34]: 
array([[21.,  4., 20., 18.,  7.],
       [ 3., 32., 40., 12., 28.],
       [21., 16., 40.,  0., 14.]])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a simple matrices trick

```
c = np.matmul(a,diag(b))
```

basically just doing matrix multiplication between `a` and a matrix whose diagonals are the elements of `b`. Maybe not as efficient but it's a nice single line solution